# Canoncial way to retrieve the IntID of an content object based on Dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity

The five.intid documentation states the following pattern for retrieving the IntID for
an object:

```
from five.intid import site
intids = site.get_intids(app.plone)
intid_obj = intids.getId(app.plone.restrictedTraverse('path/to/object')
```

Is this the canoncical way also in Plone or is there some helper/utility method
available wrapping the code above?

Comment: Just to note: Are you sure you want to use intids? Last time I asked similar question I got answers intids are not totally supported and you should avoid them...

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: it's more that intids have, in the past, caused some problems for us, especially when used in combination with relationships. I've ironed out a few wrinkles since then.

Comment: What is the alternative for using intids?

Comment: What is the usecase? IntIds were originally intended for Zope 3, where the object could be retrieved directly without destroying the acquisition chain; in Z2 it needs to store paths too just to be able to rebuild the context, so you could just use paths yourself instead of an intid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use:

```
from zope.component import getUtility
from zope.intid.interfaces import IIntIds

intid = getUtility(IIntIds).getId(object)
```

as the intid utility is registered with the local component manager.